# GCC: Section names containing the / character

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, sections

The answer to this question:

[gcc/ld: Allow Code Placement And Removal of Unused Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428032/gcc-ld-allow-code-placement-and-removal-of-unused-functions)

seems to be a very good one. However, trying to use it, I see that the section name gets truncated as soon as a slash (/) character is encountered.

`__FILE__` contains the path to the file, and thus the / character. The linker drops everything following a / character when creating a section name, eg.:

```
#define SEC_TEXT __attribute__((section(".mytext.bl/ah.c")))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
unsigned char SEC_TEXT poll(void)
```

I end up with this section name:

```
  [ 8] .mytext.bl        PROGBITS        00000000 000120 00003d 00      0   0  1
```

If I use your answer, using `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`:

```
#define __S(s) #s
#define _S(s) __S(s)
#define SECTION __FILE__ "." _S(__LINE__)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#define SEC_MYTEXT __attribute__((section(".mytext." SECTION)))
unsigned char SEC_MYTEXT poll(void)
```

I get this:

```
  [ 8] .mytext.          PROGBITS        00000000 000120 00003d 00      0   0  1
```

But you can see from the preprocessor output that it should give me a section name with the file and the line:

```
unsigned char __attribute__((section(".mytext." "/path/to/mycode/poll.c" "." "250"))) poll
```

Any way of getting around this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it's only the free Mentor Graphics Intel (x86) compiler that shows that behaviour, both 4.6.3 and 4.7.2. GCC 4.8.2 with Ubuntu 14.04 is OK with handling slashes in section names. So is the Mentor ARM compiler 4.6.3.